# Convert png into flat white and transparent using image magick

Tags: ruby, imagemagick, rmagick, minimagick

I am using image magick to convert the image1 into image2.

image1
[image: image1]

image2[image]

i tried using the following

```
convert image1.png -fuzz XX% -fill green -transparent white image2.png
```

it didn't get converted like image2.

Can anyone help me to convert image1 into image2?

Comment: Can you tell us what happened? Are you getting an error?

Comment: @milz i didn't get any error, I am unable to get expected image2. I want to convert image1 to image2.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
convert image1.png -fuzz 20% -fill green -transparent green -transparent white image2.png
```

Output Image:

[image]